# Is 0% traffic flow possible in cities skylines?

Tags: cities-skylines

I was just wondering because I have seen some low traffic cities in videos but not 0%.

Please do not attach any videos to your answers.

Comment: You said don't attach videos- but I found a video asking the same question

Comment: @ChocolateChara provide just a screenshot then

Comment: I can't really do that unless im sending a screenshot of the thumbnail because it's blocked (school).

Comment: Maybe mods? I had moments of frustration where I added workshop mods to help with diverse mechanics (like a glitch late game where you have no demand for anything) but I cant remember one that was 'no traffic jams'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume a 0% traffic is only achievable with mods. Things like this [Lifecycle Rebalance Revisited 1.6.2](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=2027161563)

Traffic is a very hard thing to manage in cities skylines, and I imagine if you have as much hours as someone that does videos about the game in detail, I would imagine they have such a mod to make one of the hardest parts of the game for no reason (in my opinion) a little, or lot easier.